# How to add a folder link to a sticky note

Tags: windows-7, sticky-notes

I am using sticky notes provided by **windows 7**. What i need to do is to add a folder from my hard disk (like *c:\temp* folder) to a sticky note. when i just put *c:\temp* folder to sticky note it is not shown as a hyperlink.
like when i add *\someip*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try typing `file://c:\temp` - that should give you a link to the file or folder location.

The back-slashes in the file path can be interchanged, so `file://c:/temp` will also work.

Comment: file:c:\temp also works. what for folder c:\temp folder (containing space)
if if do file:c:\temp folder then it only highlights file:c:\temp not whole line? i tried double quotes but not working.

Comment: @fhnaseer: Try URL encoding.  `file://c:/temp%20folder`

Comment: @surfasb is spot on. You'll need to encode the spaces as %20. Some other characters will also need encoding too. You can use online tools like [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to encode the folder and file names.